# Using array from header in another page

Tags: php, database, arrays

Ok so I have an array "$landing" in my header.php, then in my page.php I include the header.php but for some reason when I call the 'Name' field in the array in the page.php: `echo $landing['Name'];` it just doesn't work.

this is how the array is being filled up, and calling it in the header works perfectly.

```
$landing = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $str = strtolower($row['Name']);
   if ($str == $name) {
       $landing = $row;
   }
}
```

To clarify, $row and $landing are both arrays, and both have multiple fields 'Name' 'Color' 'Info'.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to make it global somehow or what's going on?

Comment: Apart from you using deprecated MYSQL extension and not using the newer MYSQLi, there's nothing wrong with that code. You need to show us more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code works somehow, now as the OP said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474178/using-array-from-header-in-another-page/18474304?noredirect=1#comment27154789_18474304).

But my old tips still hold:

- Consider using MySQLi or PDO instead of the deprecated MySQL extension!
- Why do you compare the dataset's column value on the client-side? You can do this on the MySQL side, it'll be faster!

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, $row and $landing are both arrays, and both have multiple fields 'Name' 'Color' 'Info.

Comment: OK, I have to ask this, how is $landing = $row; making $landing a string?

Comment: @Dexa Yeah, I just realized it, too (I confused it with `$str`). /cc @Started...:Your original code should actually work. Try `var_dump($landing)` after the while loop.

Comment: ok so, a var_dump on $landing shows all the right variables, when called in header.php, but it's blank when var_dump on page.php still

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom a) Do you include *page.php* in *header.php* after the *while* loop? b) Is your `echo` statement contained in a function, class or other code block? Does it live in the global scope?

Comment: wow nevermind, a var_dump is working on page.php now..It must have been a synthax error, or some glitch with wpengine, thanks for the help nonetheless!

Comment: I had included header.php in page.php, and the while loop was the first thing on the header.php. The echo statements were within pieces of html code

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom I'm glad that it works now ;) I removed the old parts of my answer except for the tips.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36363/discussion-between-startedfromthebottom-and-comfreek)

Answer (score 0):

You are, as ComFreek correctly stated, turning $landing into a string. Instead, if you're trying to add an entry to the landing array, use [] brackets which mean "add into new entry".

```
$landing = array();    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $str = strtolower($row['Name']);
   if ($str == $name) {
       $landing[] = $row;
   }
}
```

Comment: I was **not** correct because `$row` is an array (I confused it with `$str`) ;)

Comment: As we already established there was error in ComFreek answer, but anyway why would you make answer where you say "As other person answered... I'll copy answer here" :/ Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @ComFreek Right. Oops. Apart from the fact that $name is nowhere else to be found in the code, I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Dexa I actually answered the question instead of providing methods to debug and find the problem. At least I thought I did until we all find out we were wrong..

Comment: @Dexa LS97 probably thought that there were more than one matching result set. I think it was more an addition than a complete new answer (but it still justifies an answer in my opinion).

Comment: @ComFreek  I know what he meant (at least I think I do), but my opinion is that if you said user it's not array, it's a string, OP should know how to add it to array, he uses arrays in question. Anyway just my 2 cents, doesn't mean I'm right. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I cant comment LS97 post, anyway you want to use $landing["Name"] you edit LS97 code into this:

```
$landing = array();    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $str = strtolower($row['Name']);
   if ($str == $name) {
       $landing["name"] = $row;
   }
}
```

If you want to use multiple names, LS97 code is fine.

The problem is what they said. (Using $landing = $row, landing will be a string.)

Comment: Why? What is the problem? Comment pls :/

Comment: @MarcoLopezAcierno The original code was never the problem. The OP had got some other errors in the outputting code (see his comment on my answer).